# tkbutton mainloop with for loop

Tags: python

I know that two loops cannot exist at the same time, below is what I want to do. I know threading sometimes solve this problem, but is there alternative? I ask because the for loop I actually have has a lot of instructions inside, and I only check once each time it loops.

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import time
root = tkinter.Tk()
chk = ttk.Checkbutton(root, text='Click me')
chk.grid(column=0, row=0)
root.mainloop()


for i in range(len(list)):
    print(list[i])
    time.sleep(5) #actually a set of instructions that assume taking 5 seconds
    if chk.instate(['selected']):
       break
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you not to use a `for` loop and `time` for checking the state of the `Checkbutton`. Use `after` instead. The disadvantage of `time` in a tkinter program is, that you can't do anything during the 5 seconds of sleep time. The for loop and the mainloop are running on the same thread, so the mainloop has to wait until the for loop is finished. The `after` method run in the background, so your program can be used normally while waiting for the next selected-check.

Pack all the stuff from inside your for loop inside a function (here called `checkState()`) and call this every 5 seconds from the `startAfter(time, function)`. When the state of the Checkbutton is false, the "loop" continues, if it is true (selected) the "loop" stops.

```py
def checkState():
  if chk.instance(['selected']) ==False:
    startAfter(5000, checkState)

def startAfter(time, function):
  root.after(time, checkState)
```

I hope this is what you mean and that I helped you ;)

Comment: the for loop is actually involving iteration over a list, so I think it must exist.

Comment: I don't know if this is the best solution but what if you add a for loop in the checkState function. That way you are still rid of the `time.sleep`.

Comment: thanks for your help, though I end up asking another question about this, as I learnt that there is no way not to use threading.